# Configuring the Title page

Tags: jsp, title

We have 3 websites and sharing same head.jsp
I want to configure the code inside title tag below

```
<title>
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${requestScope['com.escenic.context']=='art'}">
      <c:out value="${article.title}" escapeXml="true"/> -
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${section.uniqueName != 'homepage’}”>
      <c:out value="${section.name}" escapeXml="true"/> -
    </c:when>
  </c:choose>

  <c:choose>
    <c:when test=“${wesite.name eq ‘pg’}”>
    pg website name
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${wesite.name eq ‘pk’}”>
    pk website name
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${wesite.name eq ‘ls’}”>
    ls website name
    </c:when>
  </c:choose>
</title>
```

How do i change the code if I want to add title in homepage, let say if it is in 'pg website name' Homepage, I want to display the page title as 'pg website name: expert guide'

Thank you!

Comment: Please change the title to be more descriptive.  Your title should be specific and descriptive.  Including this in the title will make people more likely to click on your question and help you out.  At the moment, it is way to vague.

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear... What I mean is, I want to change the code inside the title tag let say for homepage pg website name... to something like 'pg website name: expert guide' without affecting the other two websites title page...